# Resonance structures of lysine and cause of its basic nature

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

Lysine is one of the most important amino acids. IUPAC name it as **2,6 - diaminohexanoic acid** . But what are its resonance forms?? And can resonance tell why it is basic??? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group that constitutes the side chain is nothing but a primary amine. That explains the high pKa of ~ 10.5 (compare propylamine (pka ~10.9).  No need to invoke resonance.  Are you perhaps thinking of arginine?

[image: Lysine]

Comment: +1. Sir, first of all, thanks for the answer. I did want to know the resonating structures. So, can you please??

Comment: There is just one Lewis structure.  The charge is confined to the side-chain nitrogen.

Comment: Sir,can you tell why there is dot-dot bond between $O$ atoms? Doesn't this mean resonance??

Comment: That's the carboxylate functionality, which explains the smallest pKa of ~ 2.2

Comment: The alpha amine is also basic, though not as much.